# Разбиение строки с помощью split

Tags: java, строки

Как разбить такую строку "Иванов И.И. преподаватель" на две подстроки с помощью `split`:

1. Иванов И.И.
2. преподаватель

Answer (score 1):

Если точно не будет пробела между инициалами, то можно по точке и пробелу. Правда точка после последнего инициала исчезнет, но её можно вручную добавить:

```
String[] arr =  "Иванов И.И. преподаватель".split(". "); 
arr[0]+=".";
```

Comment: а как поступить в следующем случае? Дана строчка "Иванов И.И. Админ. в ИС (лек.) С-204 (1-11)"
Необходимо получить следующие слова по отдельности:
1) Иванов И.И.
2) Админ. в ИС
3) лек
4) С-204
5) 5-11

Comment: тут у вас получается вопрос другой уже. У меня может быть любая строка как мне получить нужную

Comment: @Samur, самым правильным решением будет не получать данные в таком виде, ибо такую строку разбирать программно - адЪ

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а если нету другой возможности?

Comment: @Samur, ну, в таком случае надо или аццкую регулярку писать (это крайне трудно, тут спец нужен) или написать аццкий алгоритм, коий, например, будет сначала по второму вхождению ". " строку резать, потом по первым " (", ")" etc